# Put multiple textboxes and labels under each other on the same column css?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, layout

[image]

Hello!
Is it possible to put multiple textboxes and labels under each other on the same column as shown in the picture by CSS coding? and how?

when i do it, it appears like this :
[image] 
                                         Thanks

Comment: What is that you really want to know here? All in all isnt it just another table in a table column?

Comment: @KemalCanKara look at the second picture i uploaded it .. the textboxes and the labels not perfectly under eachother

Comment: if the alignment is your only problem u can do that with putting a blank <td> between label and textbox <td> and give all columns an align="left"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

In your aspx page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="row"> 
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="label">Dropdown:</asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="input"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="label">Textbox 1:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="input"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="label">Textbox 2:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="input"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
```

and in your css file

```
.row{ display:block; height:30px;}
.label{ float:left; width:100px;}
.input{ float:left; width:100px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

i am hoping this will helps you..

use the `<fieldset>` tag in combination with `<label>`. [Step by step explanation](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-forms.shtml).
Then align at will.

or

take a look at here http://jsfiddle.net/Qs4pk/2/

Answer (score 1):

There are a ridiculous number of ways to do this. From simple `fieldset`'s to CSS to `table`'s (as everyone cringes). It all comes down to how ***you*** want to design the site/form. Take a look at these two examples:

**Simple**:  http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/RqdMY/

**Complex**: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/nhmjD/

Answer (score 1):

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td id="tdControlLabel" runat="server" align="right">        
              <asp:Label ID="_controlLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>              
        </td>
        <td style=" color:Red;">
            <asp:Label ID="_isMandatory" runat="server" Text="*" Width="2" />
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <asp:TextBox ID="_value" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I put this in user control and I use it where ever I want

Here is code behind

```
public bool isPassword
        {
            set
            {
                if (value) _value.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password;
            }
        }
        public string ForeignKey
        {
            get { return hdnForeignKey.Value; }
            set { hdnForeignKey.Value = value; }
        }

        public string ControlLabel
        {
            get { return _controlLabel.Text; }
            set { _controlLabel.Text = value; }
        }

        public bool IsMandatory
        {
            get { return _isMandatory.Visible; }
            set { _isMandatory.Visible = value; }
        }

        public string Value
        {
            get { return _value.Text; }
            set { _value.Text = value; }
        }

        public bool IsReadyForInput
        {
            get { return _value.Enabled; }
            set { _value.Enabled = value; }
        }

        public string ControlLabelWidth
        {
            set { tdControlLabel.Width = value; }
        }

        public bool isTextArea
        {
            set
            {
                if(value)
                {
                    _value.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
                    _value.Rows = 5;
                }
                else
                {
                    _value.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
                }
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _value.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }
```

And this is implementation

```
<uc1:ucTextBox ID="txtxName" ControlLabel="Name" ControlLabelWidth="145"
                                    runat="server" IsMandatory="true"></uc1:ucTextBox>
```